# A limit of a particular Quantum Fidelity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, mathematical-physics, trace

I have the following problem.

Let $\mathbf{\hat{\rho}}(t)$ and $\mathbf{\hat{\sigma}}(t)$ be two trace class positive operators acting on a Hilbert space of infinite dimension for all $t > 0$. More precisely assume that
$$
\mathbf{\hat{\rho}}(t):= \int p_{i}(x)e^{-ixt\mathbf{\hat{B}}}\big|\psi\big\rangle \big\langle \psi\big|e^{ixt\mathbf{\hat{B}}}dx
$$
$$
\mathbf{\hat{\sigma}}(t):= \int p_{j}(x)e^{-ixt\mathbf{\hat{B}}}\big|\psi\big\rangle \big\langle \psi\big|e^{ixt\mathbf{\hat{B}}}dx
$$

where $\mathbf{\hat{B}}$ is a self-adjoint operator with purely absolutely continuous spectrum and $\big|\psi\big\rangle$ is any vector in the Hilbert space in question, and $p_{i}$ and $p_{j}$ are probability distributions with compact support which is nonoverlapping.
I am trying to prove that
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\big\|\sqrt{\mathbf{\hat{\rho}}(t)}\sqrt{\mathbf{\hat{\sigma}}(t)}\big\|_{1}= 0  \;\; (quantum\; fidelity)$$

However, this has proven to be quite a challenge since there are no good upper bounds for the quantum fidelity in the general case were both of the operators in question are not pure. I have tried using the following celebrated bound.

$$
\big\|\sqrt{\mathbf{\hat{\rho}}(t)}\sqrt{\mathbf{\hat{\sigma}}(t)}\big\|_{1}\leq\sqrt{1-\big\|\mathbf{\hat{\rho}}(t)-\mathbf{\hat{\sigma}}(t)\big\|_{1}^{2}}
$$
but this just replaces a very difficult problem with one of equal complexity.

For the simpler version of this problem where

$$\mathbf{\hat{\rho}}(t):=e^{-ix_{i}t\mathbf{\hat{B}}}\big|\psi\big\rangle \big\langle \psi\big|e^{ix_{i}t\mathbf{\hat{B}}}
$$

and

$$
\mathbf{\hat{\sigma}}(t):=e^{-ix_{j}t\mathbf{\hat{B}}}\big|\psi\big\rangle \big\langle \psi\big|e^{ix_{j}t\mathbf{\hat{B}}}
$$

with $x_{i}\neq x_{j}$ and all of the other assumptions preserved I can easily show the analogous hypothesis.

Here

$$
 \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\big\|\sqrt{\mathbf{\hat{\rho}}(t)}\sqrt{\mathbf{\hat{\sigma}}(t)}\big\|_{1} = \big|\langle \psi\big|e^{-t(x_{i}-x_{j})\mathbf{\hat{B}}}\big|\psi\big\rangle\big| = \int e^{-t(x_{i}-x_{j})\lambda}d\mu_{\psi}(\lambda)
$$
where $d\mu_{\psi}(\lambda)$ is the absolutely continnuous spectral measure afforded by $\big|\psi\rangle$. Owing to the Riemann Lebegues lemma indeed $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\int e^{-t(x_{i}-x_{j})\lambda}d\mu_{\psi}(\lambda) = 0$. Due to this result, I am led to believe that the more general case where $\mathbf{\hat{\rho}}(t)$ and  $\mathbf{\hat{\sigma}}(t)$ are uncountable mixtures as presented above, we should have the same sort of behavior as $t\rightarrow \infty$. However, the quantum fidelity is unwieldy. Any help tackling this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If B=0, aren't rho and sigma equal (and thus your statement incorrect)?

Comment: re: Norbert, the distributions are non-overlapping and hence $\rho,\sigma$ are different.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch thank you for your response. I am actually only interested in the case where $\mathbf{\hat{B}}\neq \mathbf{0}$; my apologies for not being specific. Indeed, if $\mathbf{\hat{B}}=\mathbf{0}$ then both states in question would be the same since the probability densities would integrate out to 1.

Comment: @hulsey This is incorrect for B=0. -- The point seems that the questions demands a purely absolutely continuous spectrum, which rules out such cases.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Good point! Thank you.

Comment: @Hldngpk Note that otherwise, just requiring $B\ne0$ will not save you, counterexamples seem abundant, even in finite dimensions. (Where, of course, there is no such thing as a continuous spectrum.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I am aware of this. This is why I specified that the Hilbert space in question is infinite-dimensional and that I am focusing only on the operators $B\neq 0$ which have only purely continuous spectrum. If you can provide a counter-example under the assumptions stated in my exposition then I would love to learn about it.

Comment: @Hldngpk My point is that you don't have to specify $B\ne0$, as it is already ruled out by the spectrum.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch A but of course. Thank you. I removed that from the prompt.

Comment: Without much thought: Given you know it works without the integrals, can't you just use some CS- oder Hölder-type inequality to pull the integral out of the norm?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch if you are talking about Schatten norm theory and the generalization of H\"{o}lder's inequality found therein.. this won't help since there are no useful ways to bound $\|...\|_{1}$.  E.g. if you use CS you just get a bound of 1 and this is not Helpful.  Pulling out the integral, as far as I can tell is not possible due to the presence of the square roots. It is really the square roots that are possing a formidable hurdle

Comment: Can you verify that the states are maximally mixed in the $t\to\infty$ limit? I calculate $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho^2)=\int p(x) p(y) dx dy |\langle \psi| e^{i(y-x)Bt)}|\psi\rangle|^2$, and in the question it says the part after $dy$ should vanish. Note that mine has an "$i$" and OP's has a "$-$" in the exponential so perhaps there is a distinction. Then it is interesting that two maximally mixed states are not the same state (there are somehow two states that are "flat everywhere" and "nowhere overlapping")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neat question! Here is an almost complete answer; I encourage someone to edit my answer to tighten up the math at the end, but all of the steps are clear.

Inspired by [another inequality for fidelity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fidelity_of_quantum_states#Relationship_with_the_fidelity_between_the_corresponding_probability_distributions), let's resolve the identity using states that are Fourier transforms of eigenstates $\hat{\mathbf{B}}$; i.e., using states that are displaced by $e^{-i x t \hat{\mathbf{B}}}$:
$$\mathbb{I}=\int dx |x\rangle\langle x|;\quad e^{-i y t \hat{\mathbf{B}}}|x\rangle=|x+ y t\rangle; \quad \langle x|y\rangle=\delta(x-y).$$ These can always be found by using $|x\rangle=\int dp e^{-ixp}|p\rangle$ with $|p\rangle$ the delta-orthogonal eigenstates of $\hat{\mathbf{B}}$.

We use that the trace norm can always be rewritten using $\mathrm{Tr}(|A|)=\mathrm{Tr}(A U)$ for some unitary $U$ and the usual $|A|=\sqrt{A A^\dagger}$. The fidelity $F(\rho,\sigma;t)=||\sqrt{\rho(t)}\sqrt{\sigma(t)}||_1=\mathrm{Tr}(|\sqrt{\rho(t)}\sqrt{\sigma(t)}|)$ can then be written as
$$F(\rho,\sigma;t)=\mathrm{Tr}(\sqrt{\rho(t)}\sqrt{\sigma(t)}U)$$ for some $U$. Inserting the resolution of identity and then using a Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $|\mathrm{Tr}( A^\dagger B)|\leq \sqrt{\mathrm{Tr}(A^\dagger A)\mathrm{Tr}(B^\dagger B)}$ yields
\begin{aligned}
F(\rho,\sigma;t)=&\int dx \mathrm{Tr}(\sqrt{\rho(t)}|x\rangle\langle x|\sqrt{\sigma(t)}U)\\
=&\int dx \mathrm{Tr}(\sqrt{\rho(t)}\sqrt{|x\rangle\langle x|}\sqrt{|x\rangle\langle x|}\sqrt{\sigma(t)}U)\\
&\leq \int dx \mathrm{Tr}(\sqrt{\rho(t)}\sqrt{|x\rangle\langle x|}\sqrt{|x\rangle\langle x|}\sqrt{\rho(t)})\mathrm{Tr}(\sqrt{|x\rangle\langle x|}\sqrt{\sigma(t)}UU^\dagger \sqrt{\sigma(t)}\sqrt{|x\rangle\langle x|})\\
&= \int dx \langle x|\rho(t)|x\rangle\langle x|\sigma(t)|x\rangle.
\end{aligned} For this we simply needed that $\rho$, $\sigma$, and $|x\rangle\langle x|$ are Hermitian and that $\mathrm{Tr}(\sqrt{\rho}|x\rangle\langle x|\sqrt{\sigma}U)\leq |\mathrm{Tr}(\sqrt{\rho}|x\rangle\langle x|\sqrt{\sigma}U)|$.

Next, we expand $|\psi\rangle=\int dx \psi(x)|x\rangle$ in our chosen basis and use $e^{it \hat{\mathbf{B}}}|x\rangle=|x-t\rangle$ to compute
$$\langle x|\rho(t)|x\rangle=\int dy p_i (y) \langle x-yt|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|x-yt\rangle=\int dy p_i(y) |\psi(x-yt)|^2$$ and $$\langle x|\sigma(t)|x\rangle=\int dz p_j(z) |\psi(x-zt)|^2.$$

Putting these together, our inequality becomes
$$F(\rho,\sigma;t)\leq \int dx \int dy\int dz p_i(y) p_j(z) |\psi(x-yt)|^2 |\psi(x-zt)|^2$$ and the goal is to prove that the integral on the right-hand side vanishes in the limit of $t\to \infty$ when $p_i(x)$ and $p_j(x)$ have nonoverlapping compact support.

Now is where the hand-waving begins, but I'm sure someone can make this rigorous. Define the support of $p_i(x)$, $p_j(x)$, and $|\psi(x)|^2$ respectively as $S_i$, $S_j$, and $S_\psi$. The integrand is only nonzero for regions where $y\in S_i$, $z\in S_j$, $x-yt\in S_\psi$, and $x-zt\in S_\psi$. Since $S_i$ and $S_j$ are disjoint, we must have $|y-z|>0$ for the integrand to be nonzero (ignoring regions of zero measure). This means that the the integrand can only be nonzero if $S_\psi$ has two "spaced apart" regions with $x^\prime\equiv x-yt\in S_\psi$ and $x^\prime+(y-z)t\in S_\psi$. In the limit of $t\to\infty$, the integrand is only nonzero if there are two "infinitely spaced apart" regions $S_\psi$.

So, for any state $|\psi\rangle$ whose support in the Fourier transform basis of $\hat{\mathbf{B}}$ does not have two regions that are infinitely far apart, the relationship
$$\lim_{t\to\infty} F(\rho,\sigma;t)=0$$ holds.

Comment: thank you very much for your response.  I have a few comments. I'll present them separately.

Comment: Comment 1) It is not the case that one, as you say, may always find a basis $|x\rangle$ such that $e^{itx_{i}\mathbf{\hat{B}}}\big|x\big\rangle = \big|x+x_{i}t\big\rangle$. When $\mathbf{\hat{B}}$ is the laplacian or, any quadrature momentum, this is true. In general, this is not true however since the commutation relations $\big[ \mathbf{\hat{B}}, \mathbf{\hat{X}}\big] = i\mathbb{I}$ would need to be satisfied, where $\mathbf{\hat{X}}$ is the operator with generalized eigenvectors $\big|x\big\rangle$.

Comment: Continuation of comment 1) What you seem to imply is that there always exists $\mathbf{\hat{X}}$ for any $\mathbf{\hat{B}}$ with purely absolutely continuous spectrum such that $\big[\mathbf{\hat{B}},\;\mathbf{\hat{X}}\big]$. This, however, is not so! Consider the case where $\mathbf{\hat{B}} = f(\mathbf{\hat{P}})$, where $\mathbf{\hat{P}}$ is the momentum operator and $f(x)$ is a compactly support continuous fucntion. Can you find an $\mathbf{\hat{X}}$ satisfying $\big[\mathbf{\hat{X}},\; f(\mathbf{\hat{P}})\big] = i \mathbb{I}$ ? I think not.

Comment: Comment 2) The integral you present following the line "Putting these together, our inequality becomes" decays to zero via first noting that the convolution of two L1 functions is yet again an L1 function and then by the usage of Tonneli's theorem and a Dominated Convergence theorem argument.

Comment: Comment 3) This variational bound to the Fidelity (Nielsen and Chuang 9.2.2) is indeed an interesting approach and it had not occurred to me to use the spectral decomposition of $\mathbf{\hat{B}}$ as the POVM used for the bound. Unless I have overlooked something your approach seems to solve my problem for the special case of $\mathbf{\hat{B}}$ being a position or momentum operator but only for this case. I am wondering if this approach may now be adapted to a general $\mathbf{\hat{B}}$ with purely absolutely continuous spectrum. i.e. we start with the spectral decomposition ...

Comment: continued... we start with the spectral decomposition $e^{-itx_{i}\mathbf{\hat{B}}} = \int_{\sigma(\mathbf{\hat{B}})} e^{-itx_{i}\lambda}d\mathbf{\hat{E}}_{\lambda}$ . For the case you have worked out the spectral projector family $\mathbf{\hat{E}}_{x} = \int_{-\infty}^{x}\big|x\big\rangle\big\langle x\big| dx$ . I will think about this more. Thank you again for your ideas.

Comment: Sorry, in my second to last comment, I meant to write "It had not occurred to me to use the spectral decomposition of the conjugate operator to $\mathbf{\hat{B}$...

Comment: @Hldngpk I have nothing to add! Your comments are all spot-on: 1) is well taken, I have only proven for a certain class of operators; 2) is helpful, I appreciate you tightening that up; 3) yes since this method proves your relation for more than just pure states I feel that it should be general enough. If not, and you need another method to prove the general case, this is at least stronger evidence that your relation is valid

Comment: @Hldngpk does it help that I did not actually define $|x\rangle$ as eigenstates of anything? I simply formed them from a continuous superposition of eigenstates of $\hat{\mathbf{B}}$, and that state will obey the shift property and orthonormality property required so long as the eigenstates of $\hat{\mathbf{B}}$ are delta-orthogonal

Comment: Mechanics. The problem is that by assuming that $e^{-ity\mathbf{\hat{B}}}\big|x\big\rangle$ you have already constrained your model to the one I described, i.e. the one satisfying the Heisenberg commutation relations. What you provided is a special case of what I am after and not the full general setting.

Comment: @Hldngpk all I need is an infinite set of eigenstates of $\hat{\mathbf{B}}$ such that $\langle p|p^\prime\rangle=\delta(p-p^\prime)$ and $\int dp |p\rangle\langle p|=\mathbb{I}$, then I just define $|x\rangle=\int dp e^{-ixp}|p\rangle$. Now you might say $\hat{\mathbf{B}}$ has compact support so this is not true, and then my suggestion would be to instead look at the eigenstates of $t\hat{\mathbf{B}}$ and those will have eigenvalues spanning $\mathbb{R}$ and so the Fourier transform should be nice

Comment: @Hldngpk say we want $|x;t\rangle$ such that $e^{-iytB}|x;t\rangle=|x+y;t\rangle$. Just define $|x;t\rangle=\int dp e^{-iptx}|pt\rangle$ where $tB|pt\rangle=tB|pt\rangle$. Then $\langle x;t|x^\prime;t\rangle=\int dp \exp[i pt(x-x^\prime)]=t^{-1}\int d(pt) \exp[i (pt)(x-x^\prime)]$ where the latter integral takes the domain of $pt$ which is infinite even if $B$ has compact support

Comment: very interesting response.  I have to process it. By the way, you wrote $tB|pt\rangle=tB|pt\rangle$ above? Is this a typo? Did you mean to write $  tB|pt\rangle=tp|pt\rangle$ ?

Comment: Also, I made a typo in my second to last message. I meant to write " by assuming that $e^{-ity\mathbf{\hat{B}}}\big|x\big\rangle = \big|x+ty\big\rangle$".

Comment: by utilizing the parameter $t$ that you have introduce . Do we not have $\langle x;t\big|x;t\rangle = \frac{1}{t}\delta(0) $ ( in distribution). Which means that we have given up normalization?

Comment: @Hldngpk I'm not yet sure about normalization. Maybe the definition needs to be $|x;t\rangle=\int d(pt) exp(-iptx)|pt\rangle$, and these states are delta-orthogonal in the large-$t$ limit. This is just some intution for starting the calculation and seeing what happens